# In springframework, Validation error doesn't display rather getting HTTP Status 500

Tags: spring, validation, frameworks, thymeleaf, backing

I have a very simple application for customer data entry.
Only the new customer entry page is working and data is getting inserted in db, but when i intensionally enter more then 10 digits in mobileNo field, i get error in browser.
Here is github link https://github.com/kalyan4github/cdb.git

```
**the full error logs is type Exception report**

message Failed to convert value of type 'com.trickytechnos.cdb.domain.Customer' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.trickytechnos.cdb.domain.Customer] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'com.trickytechnos.cdb.domain.Customer' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.trickytechnos.cdb.domain.Customer] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:74)
    org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:40)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:575)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.formatValue(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.addAttribute(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.addAttribute(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:34)
    com.trickytechnos.cdb.controller.CustomerController.addCustomer(CustomerController.java:54)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.trickytechnos.cdb.domain.Customer] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
    org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:93)
    org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:64)
    org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:40)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:575)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.formatValue(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.addAttribute(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.addAttribute(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:34)
    com.trickytechnos.cdb.controller.CustomerController.addCustomer(CustomerController.java:54)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
```

**This is the output in console**

```
Field error in object 'customer' on field 'mobileNo': rejected value [12345678912]; codes [Size.customer.mobileNo,Size.mobileNo,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [customer.mobileNo,mobileNo]; arguments []; default message [mobileNo],10,0]; default message [mobileno must be 10 digit]
```

Please help me as why am i getting this error and the validation message is displayed in console instead in thymeleaf template.

Comment: Try removing the `@Valid` annotation form the customer object and perform the validation manually.

Comment: I tried removing @valid, but don't know how to manually validate. can u please commit the changes in github so that, i can pull the changes